# python pillow when I open a portrait (height greater than width) image, the image is rotated ccw 90 degrees

Tags: python, image, rotation, python-imaging-library

When I open an image which is higher than width (portrait), the image
is rotated 90 degrees ccw.

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pathlib import Path

wd = Path.cwd()
fn = wd / 'sample.jpg'

path = str(fn)
img = Image.open(path)

img.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.   Apparently show saves the image as a .png temp file, and that save loses the orientation information that is in the exif data of the jpg image.  I also had trouble with rotate.  There is some inconsistency in the Pillow image functions.  e.g. thumbnail updates the supplied image and return None.
rotate rotates the image and returns the changed image.

```
fimage.thumbnail((700,700), Image.ANTIALIAS)
simage = fimage.rotate(270)

# update.  Transpose will use EXIF data if available to 
# rotate the image to the correct orientation

from PIL import ImageOps
img = ImageOps.exif_transpose(img)
```

Reference: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose